# Reduced page size when printing via rdp

Tags: printing, windows-terminal-services

I am facing a issue with printing on some printers via RDP using the easyprinting feature. The client is windows 7 Home, and the servers is Win2K8.
The issue is if I print the same document from the Client and the server, some 3 cm is lost in the buttom of the page when printed on the server.

I have no clue where to start in debugging this issue, can anyone help me?

Comment: A  little more information: It seams like it is only the case in case we are using brother printers :/. At least the xps printer does not mess this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the printer driver on the server and see if that resolves the issue. Any other method (Easy Print, Fallback Printer, custom print inf, etc.) is a hit or miss proposition. Microsoft has done a pretty decent job of making priting more reliable in RDP sessions but it's not perfect and some cases boil down to installing the driver on the RDS/TS server.

Comment: Ok, that sound like something. Is it documented anywhere that it can have an effect? Or is it a wild shot?

Comment: Yes. Microsoft recommends that if nothing else works, that you install the printer driver on the server. I'll look for that document and post a link as soon as I find it. In the meantime you can see if one of the hotfixes at the following page (which I just discovered) helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/09/28/using-remote-desktop-easy-print-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another possible fix (if the client printer is networkable) is to create a port forward on the client router for 9100 to the printer itself and create a printer on the RDP server that points to that using the correct driver. I've had to do that when using some sort of HP All-In-One that needs a particular driver and doesn't like printing through RDP. If the client has a dynamic IP I would suggest a free DynDNS account and pointing to the hostname instead of IP.

This has worked like a champ for me a number of times.

Comment: more a workaround then solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try printer redirection software from FabulaTech. It allows redirecting printers into RDP or Citrix session, and doesn't require any additional drivers to be installed on the server.

http://www.printer-for-remote-desktop.com/